# How do I add a counter column that starts and stops at specific rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an existing DataFrame in Pandas that has a column containing 3 different values (Column1). I want to be able to create a column so that it counts each row at every "Start" and stops counting at the next "End" (Column2). What is the best way to do this? I'm not sure how to approach this problem and the output is a strict requirement.

Sample Output:

```
    Column1    Column2
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    Start      1
    0          2
    0          3
    0          4
    End        5
    0          0
    0          0
    0          0
    Start      1
    0          2
    End        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `mask` + `ffill`

This answer assumes that a `Start` appears in the DataFrame *before* an `End` appears, or it will get the filling reversed.

---

```
col = df['Column1']

m = col.ne('Start') & col.shift().ne('End')

v = col.eq('Start').mask(m).ffill().fillna(0)

v.groupby(v.ne(v.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
5     2.0
6     3.0
7     4.0
8     5.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    1.0
13    2.0
14    3.0
Name: Column1, dtype: float64
```

---

### Explanation

First, find any value that *isn't* a start or an end

```
>>> m
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13     True
14     True
Name: Column1, dtype: bool
```

Next, `mask` any invalid value and `ffill`, which means that all values in between a `Start` and an `End` with be filled with `1`

```
>>> v
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     1.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    1.0
13    1.0
14    1.0
Name: Column1, dtype: float64
```

Finally, group by consecutive repeated values, and `cumsum`.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! Do you think you could break this down for me to describe exactly what is going on so I can fully understand it?

Comment: @jxho just added a couple of the intermediate results so you can see what's going on